# Creating a sample dataset from data that is already ingested in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to create a sample dataset from the data that is currently coming into Kibana under discover and test it in logstash

Comment: Could you please give more information aout your issue like what you have tried, what issue you are facing, your sample data etc..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.